# Why is this mercurial patch not moving the file?

Tags: patch, tortoisehg

I've used TortoiseHG to export a patch that moves a file to another place. This is the content of the patch :

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Arthur Attout <arthur.attout@outlook.com>
# Date 1551095974 -3600
#      Mon Feb 25 12:59:34 2019 +0100
# Branch CBLS
# Node ID f73e7c88dbcf6de3091e1edc9360336d1c699038
# Parent  863386a2a66de9cdd6d8885912988cb4b862eef0
Unit tests + migrate unit tests int -> long


diff -r 863386a2a66d -r f73e7c88dbcf oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/invariants/InvariantTests.scala
--- a/oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/invariants/InvariantTests.scala Fri Feb 22 14:30:14 2019 +0100
+++ /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
@@ -1,948 +0,0 @@
-package oscar.cbls.test.invariants
-
- Thousands of lines ... 
-

diff -r 863386a2a66d -r f73e7c88dbcf oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/unit/InvariantTests.scala
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/unit/InvariantTests.scala   Mon Feb 25 12:59:34 2019 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,877 @@
+package oscar.cbls.test.unit
+ Same thousands of lines ... 
+
```

This is the only thing the patches do. It moves the file `InvariantTests` from `invariants` to `unit`.

When I import the patch in tortoiseHG it gives the following error

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 0
1 out of 1 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/invariants/InvariantTests.scala.rej
patching file oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/unit/InvariantTests.scala
adding oscar-cbls/src/test/scala/oscar/cbls/test/unit/InvariantTests.scala
abandon : patch failed to apply
[command returned code 255 Mon Apr 15 19:55:02 2019]
```

After that, this is the content of my working directory

[image]

The file is not moved.

What does this 255 error mean ? Why isn't the patch simply applying an moving the file properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial [doc](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#diff-formats) clearly states:

> Mercurial's default format for showing changes between two versions of
> a file is compatible with the unified format of GNU diff, which can be
> used by GNU patch and many other standard tools.
>
> While this standard  format is often enough, it does not encode the following information:
>
> - executable status and other permission bits
> - copy or rename information
> - changes in binary files creation or deletion of empty files

In order to have this data in patch, you have to create git-compatible patch with `-git` (AFAICR) option, also available in THG GUI

Comment: Mmmh the weird thing is that this patch was created by tortoiseHG workbench (Export > Export patch).. And i'm importing it in tortoiseHG workbench as well.